# How can I crop black corners from a scanned image?

Tags: python, image-processing, python-imaging-library, scikit-image

Scans/photocopies often miss the corner which comes out black. How can these black corners be made white using python with numpy, pillow or skimage?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Create a mask with all black objects (`mask = image < threshold`)
2. Remove objects touching the border (`new_mask = segmentation.clear_border(mask)`)
3. Which objects were removed? `objs = (new_mask != mask)`
4. Fill those objects with white: `image[objs] = 1` (or 255, if dtype int).

If you need to make sure that the objects replaced by white are triangles, you can use `skimage.measure.regionprops` to further examine each one.